# Structured Data (ld-json) with multiple @Types

Tags: seo, structured-data, ldjson

Having reviewed popular websites there appear to be two different to structured data. Most sites incorporate an `Organization` type and a type to reflect the content of the page, `Webpage` or `NewsArticle` for example.

Some sites split these into separate  blocks whilst others incorporate it using `@graph`. Whilst there doesn't seem to be an issue with either approaches what if a page reflects multiple `types`.

Say it is a `Webpage` but also contains a few FAQs. This would make it an `FAQpage` as well. The list could go on if we start incorporating images and videos. Can all of these be listed in the page's structured data and are there any SEO advantages or disadvantages in doing so.

Take a look at [apple.com/arcade](https://www.apple.com/arcade). Their approach is to use two structured data scripts, one for `Organization` and one for `FAQpage` to reflect that the page contains FAQs. Why do they not also have `Webpage` type to reflect the rest of the content on the page?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean separate top-level multi-types in structured data for one content, then this is a content structure representation error.
Every content of any web page is an HTML document. Each document has only one subject of content. In the main content, it is a good idea to use the H1 element to introduce the subject. In structured data, a top-level type is used to represent a subject.
The content may have multiple sections/paragraphs. In this case, structured data can have branches with embedded types representing the topics of sections/paragraphs. Read more **[1d. Embedded items](https://schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_embedded)** of Schema and **[mainEntity(OfPage) property](https://schema.org/docs/datamodel.html#mainEntityBackground)** of Schema.

Clear structured data markup helps present the structure of the content in search results, which in turn helps users easily navigate the content and jump straight to their goal.

Comment: Now I've had a few days to research, this has been debated extensively. And there is nothing inherently wrong with either approach but the @graph method was preferred. And you can do what you say would be a "content structure representation errors" as you can validate yourself by looking at the source code of major brands to see the same situation and then running it through a search engine validator. See the discussion: https://github.com/json-ld/json-ld.org/issues/96

Comment: Please note that the element @graph is used to group several nodes as it is in the Gitnub example and in the guide JSON-LD https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-syntax/#named-graphs .